# Android divide activity into two parts

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, effect, divide

Currently I'm developing an application for an Android tablet. I search for a method or approach to divide the screen into two pieces and make a subview visible. I don't know where I found this effect (iOS or Android app).

For illustration I have two pictures attached:

[image]

After a click on View X a subview should appear exactly below (the rest of the screen will be moved down):

[image]

Does anyone know this effect?
Greetings!

Answer (score 1):

in android studio, you can inflate a fragment into your activity.

Here's the example:

in Main2Activity.java

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

        final FrameLayout frameLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.frameLayout);
        Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                PlusOneFragment myf = new PlusOneFragment();
                frameLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                transaction.add(R.id.frameLayout, myf);
                transaction.commit();

            }
        });
    }
}
```

in activity_main2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.testing.testinglibraryapps.Main2Activity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button3">

    </FrameLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/frameLayout" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/frameLayout" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

take a look, i put a trick of framelayout visibility to put the view under them going down.

and for PlusOneFragment in my example, u can change it with your own fragment

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this is many way. The easiest I can think of is to have a View you can simply show/hide directly.

Layout:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation=vertical>


    <LinearLayout   <!-- this is the top layout -->
        android:id:@+id/myTopLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation=horizontal>

        .... YOUR LAYOUT VIEWS ....

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout   <!-- this is layout you will show/hide -->
        android:id:@+id/myShowHideLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation=horizontal
        android:visibility="gone">

        .... YOUR LAYOUT VIEWS ....

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout   <!-- this is the bottom layout -->
        android:id:@+id/myBottomLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation=horizontal>

        .... YOUR LAYOUT VIEWS ....

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Now, in your activity just show or hide you middle layout where you want like so:

```
LinearLayout myShowHideLayout;

... onCreate(...){

    myShowHideLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id. myShowHideLayout);
    myShowHideLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```